# How to change createMaterialBottomTabNavigator label style (react-native)?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[createMaterialBottomTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html) is a really nice solution for adding bottomTabNavigation on `react-native`, but I hadn't have found a way to style it's labels, is it possible at all?

Comment: you should use `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` instead, its label can be styled and use `tabBarPosition: bottom` to set tab in bottom

Comment: you can use `navigationOptions ` to style the navigator and label. did you get a chance to check it!

Comment: I tested the doc produced for TabNavigator (`labelStyle`) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 8):

The official documentation for (react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs) doesn't provide anything for styling the label, yet you can style them as below:

```
navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: <Text style={{fontFamily : "pacifico", textAlign : "center"}}>Meals</Text>,
    tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => {
        return (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="food-fork-drink" size={23}
            color={tabInfo.tintColor}></MaterialCommunityIcons>)
    },
    tabBarColor: "#222f3e"
}
```

Directly apply styles to the `tabBarLabel` by wrapping it in `Text` component.

Comment: This does not work for react navigation 5, but for react navigation 4.

Answer (score 5):

In `React Navigation V6`, You can try this.

```
<Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={Home}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: <Text style={styles.tabBarLabel}>Home</Text>
    }}
/>

// Stylesheet

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabBarLabel: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: Colors.darkGreen,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

Comment: i don't understand why they have specified its type as string (tabBarLabel type), when it works fine with Elements too.

Comment: It seems not to care much about Typescript 